# Google drive file system automatically mounted

Tags: 20.04, google-drive, gvfs

I installed ubuntu a few days ago, and just found out my entire google drive has been mounted as a vfs. The path is: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=<username>`. I dont recall ever consenting to this (even though its a nice feature). Does this file system come automatically installed with every ubuntu installation?

Comment: You DID consent when you added your Google account in online accounts and enabled "Use for > Files". If you don't want that option make sure to disable it. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this file system come automatically installed with every ubuntu installation?

No.

> I dont recall ever consenting to this (even though its a nice feature).

You did.

Online accounts, option Google when you connect to your google login the option "files" when active is allowed to create a network connection to your drive.